# Can SimuLTE and 80211p be used together in veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins, simulte

After looking through the list of modules on the official `Veins` website, I found that `Veins-LTE` is no longer in use and will be replaced by `SimuLTE`.

So, I imported `SimuLTE` into `OMNeT++` and looked at the source code. However, it is questionable whether this can be integrated with the existing `Veins` 80211p demo.

Isn't it impossible to alternate between 80211p and LTE communication by adding `SimuLTE` code to the existing `RSUExampleScenario`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/veins/veins_hetvnet for a sample combination of Veins, INET, and SimuLTE.

It integrates code from the SimuLTE cars simulation as well as AlertSender and AlertReceiver code into a simulation that sends packets via both WLAN and LTE.

Comment: Thanks your advice. I will refer to the code for this repository project that you recommended.